# Select rows where column A is not unique and column B is unique?

Tags: join, sqlite

Suppose I have the following table:

```
MyTable
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
 column_a TEXT
 column_b TEXT
```

Now I want to return all rows where column_a is not unique, but where column_b is unique. So if I have the following data in the table:

```
id  column_a    column_b
1   A           x
2   B           x
3   A           y
4   A           x
5   B           x
6   C           z
```

I want the SQL statement to return this:

```
id  column_a    column_b
1   A           x
3   A           y
```

because column_a is the same in both rows but column_b differs. The rows with column_a="B" have the same value in column_b, so they should not be returned. And the row with column_a="C" has a unique column_a, so it shouldn't be returned either. How would I do that?

I've come half way by the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
JOIN
(
    SELECT column_a, column_b
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY column_a
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) TmpTable
ON MyTable.column_a = TmpTable2.column_a
WHERE MyTable.column_b != TmpTable.column_b
```

but that omits the last of the rows that I want to return, so in the above example it would only return

```
id  column_a    column_b
1   A           x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(id),
       column_a,
       column_b
FROM MyTable
WHERE column_a IN (SELECT column_a
                   FROM MyTable
                   GROUP BY column_a
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column_b) >= 2)
GROUP BY column_a,
         column_b
```

Comment: Works great, but I'm not clear on why you suggested using MIN(id)? It seems to work just as well if I use just id or even *...?

Comment: A group (defined by a unique combination of `column_a` and `column_b`) might have multiple records. Which record is chosen to return the `id` value is random unless you use some aggregate function.